# dividing template in a grid system

Tags: html, css, templates, grid

I've just been given a new project, and first of all, I need to build the html/css. We use 24 column bootstrap grid system (as default for all of them), and I feel quiet hard to "decide" how to divide the template (the designer gives me a .png file with the design, and I have to transform it in code.

Is there any trick, software, pattern... (anything!!) you use in these cases?

I was thinking it would be very cool to have the grid drawn on the screen, but obviously, just the lines, to be able to see what is underneath. Does something like this exist?

Thank you

Comment: Photoshop and the original PSD file.

Comment: That is kind of complicated :S our designer works with Fireworks (I know, nobody else uses that program for layers), and I'm in linux mint (cinammon), so I'm using GIMP. She always moans about that she looses lots of time sending me every image separately because I am not able to see her layers, but my boss refuses to pay for fireworks, because we only have this problem with her. Is it possible to do it in gimp like you mentioned in photoshop?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry Paulie, I didn't know :S. I see it more as a problem though :S I arrived to the point that the designer tells me it doesn't look the same as her template, because the spaces! and I have the issue because she uses Fireworks and I don't. I asked for a recommendation because I don't even know if it is possible :S, but it is to solve a problem...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can open the .png in Gimp and add guides for each of the 24 columns - http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-concepts-image-guides.html. But it seems like a really backwards way of doing things, as a png is a flat image, so you can't see layers (You can if you open it in Fireworks only though), or get font sizes, or any drop shadow styles, since the text of the png won't be editable, and you would have to do it by eye. Personally it seems like a broken process.

Comment: There are photoshop grids on the internet that you can open in gimp. Just choose the right width and put it over the PNG. it works good.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at something like this : http://alefeuvre.github.io/foundation-grid-displayer/ A Javascript bookmarklet for a Bootstrap grid system.

Comment: Hi eve, there's an extension on chrome 'boostrap overlay' don't know if it can help u...